# Problem with installation of DB2

Tags: 13.04, database, ibm

I have a problem with installation of IBM DB2, it tells me it didn't find libpam.so. Is there a package I have to install to correct the problem?

I used to find a solution on the web but I found nothing that managed to correct my problem.

Answer (score 1):

My worries is, that Ubuntu is not a supported system for DB2. if you look into this document: (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.udb.apdv.gs.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0023433.htm) you will see, that Ubuntu is not listed there, but all red-hat-like systems are.

U can try to discover unsupported install of DB2 (I will not recommend it), or you can choose the proper way with different Linux distribution.

For development purposes you can stay on Ubuntu and run DB2 in a Virtual machine (VirtualBox, http://www.howopensource.com/2013/04/install-virtualbox-ubuntu-ppa/) and virtualize the supported server. For production server purpose better to choose proper OS, it will run on server, anyway, does not matter that this is not Ubuntu.

Comment: So should I install OpenSUSE instead of Ubuntu in order to install DB2 on my system? I look for a free system like Ubuntu is.

Comment: @Steve: If you like Ubuntu desktop, you can try the virtualisation way... You will need DB2 on the server anyway... and server environment does not differ so much on Suse or Fedora or Ubuntu. Your desktop is one thing, DB2 installation on the server is another. So you can try following: Ubuntu 13.04 desktop, Virtualbox, Virtualised FedoraCore4 and DB2 on it. I would choose Fedora as it is the most similar to RHEL, which is widely used in production systems.

Answer (score 0):

Find out where `libpam.so.0` exists on your machine under `/lib`.
Copy this `libpam.so.0` to `/lib` (don't create a soft link)

Answer (score 0):

Using Ubuntu Server I had the same issue. Just do the following steps:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install libpam0g:i386
```